# openssh-server Permission denied, please try again

Tags: сервер, ssh, openssh

Сегодня  рано утром поднял сервер решил  законнектится по *ssh* и при вводе пароля выводит сообщение:

> Permission denied, please try again**

Как исправить эту проблему?

---

Сервер установлен на виртуальный машину сеть настройн Сетевой мост eth0. На основном машине пингует отлично

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.1 [10.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.0.0.1" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchang
```

Comment: sudo используете?

Comment: Я использовал sudo  бесталку

Comment: Все очень просто. При подключении SSH просто укажите ключ `$ ssh -vvv <domain-or-ip>` и подключайтесь. Там будет все очень понятно и подробно написано, правда на английском и в терминах SSH, зато подробно

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от настроек сервера и sshd

Этапы, через которые вы проходите:

1. DNS до домена, если домен, а не IP-адрес. Проверяется обычным ping или службой DNS напрямую
2. Подключение на порт SSH. Firewall/iptables должны пропускать. Проверяется через wireshark наблюдением за установлением соединения или в консоли через `ssh -vvv`, он расскажет подробно, что происходит
3. Установление соединения самого SSH, тут куча вариантов - запрет входа root, запрет авторизации по паролям, разрешение авторизации только под конкретными пользователями так далее. Тут самый надежный вариант - внимательное чтение вслух каждой строки конфигурации sshd.conf на сервере. Также может помочь и `ssh -vvv` опять же, он подробно расскажет, что происходит между клиентом и сервером

Пройдите этот путь аккуратно и вдумчиво, и в итоге поймете в чем проблема. И как следствие - исправите.

Comment: Использовал ssh -vvv и вот

Comment: `-vvv` говорит клиенту подробно выводить, что происходит с подключением и что он делает, что получает от сервера. У вас подключение устанавливается, пароль спрашивается, но не подходит. Дальше смотрите конфигурацию sshd, именно она решает, где проверяется логин/пароль

Comment: Судя по вашему выводу, вы подключаетесь под пользователем `root`, который в большинстве конфигураций sshd по умолчанию запрещен для входа опцией `PermitRootLogin`. Также стоит проверить опции `PasswordAuthentication`, которая должна разрешать вход под паролем (скорее всего включена, иначе бы он у вас пароль не спрашивал) и `PermitEmptyPasswords`, на случай если у вас пустой пароль

Answer (score 1):

Permission denied - скорее всего стоит шел который нельзя запустить. Проблему надо поискать на сервере.

```
grep username /etc/passwd
```

Что покажет? у меня вот шел стоит /bin/bash

```
eri:x:1000:1000:Александр:/home/eri:/bin/bash
```